# Mac Virtual Screens order keeps changing

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

I am using my Macbook Pro with 2 external monitor, both of them is connected through mini displayport. One of my external monitor has 3 virtual desktop. (While the built in monitor and the other one has only 2)

My problem is that the virtual screens on the monitor with 3 desktop keeps shifting their orders randomly. I don't know what does cause this but it's really annoying.

How can I prevent the shifting of the virtual desktops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [the following:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4825098?tstart=0)

1. Open *System Preferences*
2. Open *Mission Control*
3. Uncheck "Automatically rearrange spaces"

Answer (score 0):

In mac Sonoma 14

1. system preference
2. Desktop and dock
3. turn off "Automatically rearrange spaces based on most recent use"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).